# LiveData: проблема с очередностью или задержкой или асинхронностью

Tags: java, android, kotlin, асинхронность, livedata

У меня возник странный баг и я не могу понять в чем проблема.
Суть кода:
у меня есть 2 `LiveData`.
1 - для данных из инета. либо они есть, либо они `null`.
2 - `Boolean` статус работы. true - при начале работы. `false` - по удачному завершению. `null` - если данные из инета тоже `null`.

```
 suspend fun getGms(platform: String, nickName: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { 
        loadFlag.postValue(true) 
        
        gmsInet.postValue(getGmsFromInet(platform, nickName)) 
 
        if (loadFlag.value != null) loadFlag.postValue(false) 
 
    } 
 
 private suspend fun getGmsFromInet(platform: String, nickName: String): _GamerStats? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        val ret: _GamerStats? = remoteModel.getGmsFromInet(platform, nickName) 
        if (ret == null) loadFlag.postValue(null) 
        return@withContext ret 
}
```

Проблема в строчке  `if (ret == null) loadFlag.postValue(null)`
я вижу в логах, что приходит `ret` и правда пришел `null`, а вот флаг `loadFlag` не меняется. он становится `false`.
если я поставлю задержку хотя бы в `1 мс` - то все будет работать как надо.

```
 if (ret == null) loadFlag.postValue(null) 
  delay(1) 
  return@withContext ret
```

игрался с разными Dispatchers - разницы нет.
словно строчка `loadFlag.postValue(null)` выполняется асинхронно от остального.
не могу понять, где моя ошибка или что я упускаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так и есть. Метод postValue() работает из фонового потока, поэтому и значение приходит туда так сказать с задержкой.
Можете использовать setValue(), работающее как раз из основного потока, тогда все активные наблюдатели мгновенно получат новое значение.
За всеми подробностями милости прошу в документацию : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)

Comment: спасибо большое! теперь даже вижу, что для работы с LiveData нужен Dispatchers.Main )) а то знать знал - но не видел никаких припятствий на другие Dispatchers